# Error running my Azure Functions created with Python Locally, Func Start doesn't fail

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to run my azure functions locally (using Postman) for testing. To do this I am accessing via command line (cmd) and run "func start".
Once I run this function in my azure function folder, the command line gives me a huge error that I can't paste into this question because it's so big, but I know it's attributed to Python modules .
After that error, the cmd still gives me a list of azure functions. To better understand my problem, I leave here a set of images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have already reviewed the requirement.txt and there are all the libraries that should be installed. I also checked that these libraries were installed on my PC and in the .venv that is created for the azure functions.

Here I leave a copy of my requirement.txt (I must also mention that I already uninstalled and installed the requirements)

```
azure-functions == 1.13.3
chardet == 5.1.0
azure-storage-blob == 12.15.0
pandas == 1.5.3
pyodbc == 4.0.34
SQLAlchemy == 1.4.39
statsmodels == 0.13.2
datetime == 5.1
numpy == 1.21.5
adal == 1.2.7
requests == 2.28.1
cchardet == 2.1.7
Office365-REST-Python-Client == 2.3.16
openpyxl == 3.0.10
```

I hope someone can give me a clue as to what mistake I may be making.
Greetings and thanks!

Comment: Can you first install all the modules from requirements.txt with pip install pandas in your terminal  and the run your function with func host start? Also, Instead of mentioning version number can you just include pandas in your requirements.txt and try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried running the below Azure function and got results as below:-

**My requirements.txt**

```
azure-functions
pandas
pyodbc
```

**My init.py**

```py
import  logging

import  azure.functions  as  func

import pyodbc

import  pandas  as  pd

 
def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')


# Define connection string and query

connection_string = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=siliconserver654.database.windows.net;Database=silicondb987;Uid=siliconuser;Pwd=Watermelon@123;"

query = "SELECT * FROM <table_name>"

  

# Create connection and retrieve data using pandas

with  pyodbc.connect(connection_string) as  conn:

df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)

  

# Return the first 10 rows of data as a JSON response

return  func.HttpResponse(df.head(10).to_json(), mimetype="application/json")
```

When I ran my function app by **Pressing F5 key or fn + F5 key**  or `func host start` .
The Function app ran like below, installed the packages and triggered HTTP Request.

```py
func host start
```

[image]

[image]

**Browser:-**

[image]

If the above method does not work, Try to install your packages by using pip install  in your terminal and then run the Function app again:-

**Code:-**

```py
pip install pyodbc
```

```py
pip install pandas
```

```py
 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**Output:-**

[image]
In your virtual environment **(venv)** check if the packages are installed like below:-

[image]

I tried running the Function app in Python Version 3.11 as well as 3.10 and it triggered successfully.

**Reference:-**

[Pandas import causing problems with Azure Function - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/337455/pandas-import-causing-problems-with-azure-function)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, this error usually show up when the python version defined in the functionapp isn't the same as the version you're running locally.

Make sure that the versions, locally (3.9) and the functionapp, are the same.